# Creating Angular app in node JS causing errors

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I created my first angular app in nodeJS I am getting these errors.

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall E:\Angular_Projects\my-first-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.2.1 postinstall E:\Angular_Projects\my-first-app\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall E:\Angular_Projects\my-first-app\node_modules\karma\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> @angular/cli@8.3.22 postinstall E:\Angular_Projects\my-first-app\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1191 packages from 1051 contributors and audited 18835 packages in 676.854s

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried running npm audit fix and got these errors.

```
E:\Angular_Projects>npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\anant\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-10T18_53_39_633Z-debug.lo
```

I have just installed nodejs and tried creating my first app in angular and got these errors. I m new to node js and angular. Please help.

Comment: Those aren't errors, just warnings.  You have to be in the project directory where the package.json is, right now you're in `E:\Angular_Projects` so I assume there's a subdirectory you need to change into.

Comment: Oh, I just have to get into the subdirectory. That's it ah! Thanks